# Flask-WTF and field name

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'd like to change `name` attribure of `SubmitField` (which is "submit" by default). What have I tried:

```
from flask.ext.wtf import Form, SubmitField

class BaseForm(Form):
    submit = SubmitField('Create', id='submit_button', name='submit_button')  #1
    submit = SubmitField('Create', id='submit_button', _name='submit_button')  #2

    def __init__(self, edit=None, *args, **kwargs):
        self.submit.kwargs['name'] = 'submit_button'   #5
        self.submit.kwargs['_name'] = 'submit_button'   #6
```

All of them failed with different error. If I removing `name` or `_name` parameter all working fine. I found that `name` attribute is passed by `flask.ext.wtf.Form` but I have no sense how to fix it.

**NOTE:** I am using not trivial import of my form: it is imported in run-time, inside of view's method, not at the top of file. I cannot and will not change it because of technical issues. I.e. if I copy-pasting my code in IDLE it is working ok. But if I importing this code inside `port` method of MethodView it is fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at extending the SubmitField itself with a custom constructor. See an example [here](https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/fields.html#fields-with-custom-constructors)

Basically you would do something like:

```
class CustomSubmitField(SubmitField):
    def __init__(self, label='', validators=None,_name='',**kwargs):
        super(SubmitField, self).__init__(label, validators, **kwargs)
        custom_name = "whatever"
        self._name = custom_name
```

Comment: The link is dead

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way to change the name is to change the name of the field:

```
class BaseForm(Form):
    # This one's name will be submit_button
    submit_button = SubmitField('Create')
    # This one's name will be another_button
    another_button = SubmitField('Do Stuff')
```

Comment: Your sample changes `label` of control, not its name. Name is attribute if `<input>` tag, and label is what user see.

Comment: @AlexG.P. - have you looked at the generated output?  The names of the inputs in the HTML should change based on name of the property in the `Form` subclass - that's how you can do things like this: `class SomeForm(Form): firstname = TextField("My Name")` rather than `class SomeForm(Form): firstname= TextField("My Name", name_="firstname")`.